# Distinction between methods called from irb and from elsewhere in program code?

Tags: ruby

I've written a module that contains a single public method called 'assemble' and several private helper methods. This module is included into a larger class that does various and sundry things. The method itself accepts a string containing a Mips 32 assembly instruction, and returns a string of 32 ones or zeros representing the 'assembled' instruction in binary.

There are two ways this method can be called: explicitly by the user from irb, and programmatically from elsewhere in the code itself. I want for the method to have different output depending on how it was called. When called from within the program itself, just silently return the bitstring, but when called explicitly from irb I want to print a line of informational text which breaks down the assembled instruction into it's associated fields.

Reading the irb docs I see there are various methods defined for configuration. At first I tried:

```
print "blah blah blah" if defined? conf.prompt_i
```

This did not work because `conf.prompt_i` is presumably not in scope from within the method call. I then tried this:

```
print "blah blah blah" if $0 == "irb"
```

and this did work when the method was called from irb, but as you can probably guess the global is too global and triggered the print statement when the method was called from within the program as well.

So my question is: is there some way to tell from within a method whether that method was typed directly into irb, or called from some other part of a program that has been loaded into irb? Perhaps there is some other way to achieve the two different outputs I haven't considered?

Here's a typical usage session in irb to demonstrate the difference between the calls:

```
>> load 'mips.rb'
=> true
>> vm = Mips32.new
=> #<Mips32:0x1009e23b>
>> vm.assemble("add $s0,$t0,$t1") # called explicitly by user
Opcode: 000000 RS: 01000 RT: 01001 RD: 10000 Shamt: 00000 Function: 100000
=> "00000001000010011000000000100000"
>> vm.load_file("mips.s")
=> true
>> vm.dump_program data # calls 'assemble' method to display bitstrings
0x00400000: ori  $s0,$zero,250   00110100000100000000000011111010
0x00400004: ori  $s1,$zero,300   00110100000100010000000100101100
etc....
```

Thanks for consideration...

Comment: "the global is too global and triggered the print statement when the method was called from within the program as well." I am confused.  `def foo; puts :irb if $0=="irb"; end;  foo` works in the irb but not from the other ways (`ruby -e` / `ruby file.rb`). Well, if you are willing to try *pry* you can use hooks. Here is **very** basic example: `f=Object.new; def f.assemble;end; Pry.config.hooks.add_hook(:before_eval, :my_hook1) do |a, b|;
  puts "You entered: #{a}.";
  puts "You typed it directly" if a.match '.assemble';
end;f.assemble; #You entered: f.assemble;
# .;
# You typed it directly;`

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have is that the program is always used from irb...saving me from having to write my own interactive shell for the program, so the global $0 is always in scope. I think I have found a solution however...see below....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so I answered my own question.

Added some code like this:

```
s = Kernel.caller[0]
print "blah blah blah" if s[(s.index("`")+1)..-2] == "irb_binding"
```

Seems to be working perfect after some brief tests...

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce a separate `Instruction` class with a custom `inspect` method, something like this:

```
class Instruction

  attr_accessor :opcode, :rs, :rt, :rd, :shamt, :function

  def initialize(opcode, rs, rt, rd, shamt, function)
    @opcode, @rs, @rt, @rd, @shamt, @function = opcode, rs, rt, rd, shamt, function
  end

  def inspect
    sprintf("Opcode: %06b RS: %05b RT: %05b RD: %05b Shamt: %05b Function: %06b", opcode, rs, rt, rd, shamt, function)
  end

  def to_s
    sprintf("%06b%05b%05b%05b%05b%06b", opcode, rs, rt, rd, shamt, function)
  end

  def to_str
    to_s
  end

end
```

IRB calls `inspect`:

```
irb(main):001:0> inst = Instruction.new(0x00, 0x08, 0x09, 0x08, 0x00, 0x20)
#=> Opcode: 000000 RS: 01000 RT: 01001 RD: 01000 Shamt: 00000 Function: 100000
irb(main):002:0> puts inst
# 00000001000010010100000000100000
#=> nil
irb(main):003:0> "foo" + inst
#=> "foo00000001000010010100000000100000"
irb(main):004:0> "foo#{inst}bar"
#=> "foo00000001000010010100000000100000bar"
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Interesting code, but I think I may have found a more succinct solution myself. `Kernel.caller` returns an array containing lines in the stack trace, of which element[0] will contain the name of the calling method which can be parsed...so I will be able to tell if the `assemble` method was called from `dump_program_data` or not. Going to play with this for a bit and see if I can get it to work.